# How to append content to a list in a class without impacting other instances of it?

Tags: python, list, multiple-instances

I try to append content to a list in a class, the problem is when I do it for one of my instances, it has the same effect on the others.
This is a simplified version of my code:

```
class Dir:
    content = []
    name = None

home = Dir()
home.name = "home"
home.content.append("Desktop")

sys = Dir()
sys.name = "home"

print(str(home.content))
print(str(sys.content))
```

When I execute the script, the result is:

```
['Desktop']
['Desktop']
```

Comment: use the __init__() method https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=class#module-dataclasses

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your instance variables in the constructor:

```py
class Dir:
  def __init__(self):
    self.content = []
    self.name = None
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a class like this:

```py
class Dir:
    content = []
    name = None
```

both `content` and `name` start off as class attributes, which are available immediately as `Dir.content` and `Dir.name`.

Each time you create an instance of the class: `home = Dir()`, the instance gets copies of the same references, so `home.content == Dir.content` and `home.name == Dir.name`.

However, when you execute: `home.name = "home"`, then you overwrite the instance variable's `name` attribute with a reference to `"home"`.

Now `Dir.name == None` still, but `home.name == "home"`.

Now the next part: `home.content.append("Desktop")` you only reference the `content` attribute to call the `append()` method. Now, both the class and instance `content` attribute contain `['Desktop']`.

Make sure you read this excellent article by [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)